How results the values of the x-, y-, z-location and the placement in the world-origin of a .shp-file in Blender(GIS)?
After importing a .shp-file in BlenderGIS (Blender 3.6.2 and BlenderGIS 2.2.10) with correct crs, the orange dot (?) has a location, which is not in the world-origin.
1 (green): How and for what is that orange dot calculated (in the items panel location x,y,z)?
2 (blue): By the way how is the placement of the imported geometry in the world-origin calculated (the coordinates in the blender properties under custom properties points exactly on the world-origin)?

I thougt the orange dot is the center of mass. But when go to Object -> Set Origin -> Geometry to Origin -> Bounds Center the position of the geometry changed but the orange dot is on the same location/position (in comparison to the world-origin).
The placement of the .shp-file above that world-origin (with the given coordinates) could be because of the median-calculation?
In further steps I will create a TIN and after it an IFC 4x3 Terrain-Model with BlenderBIM. The Map-Conversion or georeferenced placement depends on that coordinates. That's why I want to know, what that point exactly is.

Welcome to BSE. I don't see what your problem is here, moving the origin of the object to the center of mass calculates where most of the vertices are. You can set the origin to the cursor in the same menu.

Thank you! Well sorry the more I think about it the more I don't understand my problem either. When I change the world origin and the placement is different after it, the coordinates not changing... so the coordinates are allways the caculation of the median equals default world-origin?

@KISKAart I can't move the orange dot with "geometry to origin" by "bounds center" neither by "median center" to origin. With "origin to geometry" the orange dot do not change the position with "median center" (green) but moves to blue with "bounds center". However the orange dot is not allowed to move, when it is the center of mass. The world-origin should move to the orange dot.

Ok, you can edit your question so we can see what result you want and what you're getting, e.g. I place the 3D cursor, add an object, but its origin stays at the world origin.
